# How to read each line at once, save the information in that line and then move onto the next line in Java

Tags: java, algorithm, readfile

I'm having this problem, I think it's basically just algorithm but I can't figure it out though I try multiple ways. I have a file name "employees.txt". Each line in this file is a record, what I want to do is read a line from this file, extract the information of an employee, save that record to a List, then move onto the next line, repeated till the end of the file.

This is what I tried so far. One more thing is that I have to use Scanner, not other stream readers

```
 public void inputData(Scanner scanner) {
        if (employeeFile.exists()){
            try {
                scanner = new Scanner(employeeFile);
                String newLine = System.getProperty("line.operator");
                StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
//                ArrayList<String> data = new ArrayList<>();
                int count = 0;
                while (scanner.hasNextLine()){
                    str.append(scanner.nextLine());
                    System.out.printf("%s + %d\n", str, count);
                    count++;

                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }else

            System.out.println("File not exists!!!");
    }
```

Here is the records in "employees.txt", each record separated by a new line

```
D, 1, John Smith, 02-12-1971, 42 Victoria St. Hurstville NSW 2456, 10001, AVAILABLE
D, 2, Peter Taylor, 01-12-1970, 42 Victoria St. Hurstville NSW 2456, 10008, ON LEAVE
D, 3, John Doe, 03-23-1966, 12 Station St. Dapto NSW 2530, 10002, AVAILABLE
D, 4, John Gray, 05-05-1988, 16 Station St. Dapto NSW 2530, 10004, AVAILABLE
D, 5, Adam Taylor, 01-01-1980, 42 Church St. City NSW 2300, 10003, ON LEAVE
D, 6, Michael Jones, 03-05-1975, 23 Waterloo Ave. Surry Hills NSW 2502, 10012, AVAILABLE
D, 7, Frederic Jones, 02-10-1978, 3 Victoria St. Redfern NSW 2420, 20002, BUSY
D, 8, Peter O'Brien, 02-28-1983, 19 Lucas Dr. Horsley NSW 2530, 20003, 'BUSY'
A, 9, John Lucas, 12-16-1966, 20 Huxley St. Horsley NSW 2530, SUPPORT
A, 10, John Fox, 10-15-1975, 18 Victoria St. Hurstville NSW 2456, DIRECTOR
D, 11, Adam Fox, 08-10-1974, 45 Victoria St. Hurstville NSW 2456, 30005, BUSY
D, 12, Phillip Cox, 12-12-1985, 5 The Avenue Rockdale NSW 2300, 40002, BUSY
D, 13, Andrew K Smith, 04-04-1969, 42 Bambaramba Ave. Pennant Hills NSW 2556, 20045, AVAILABLE
A, 14, Andrew R Smith, 04-01-1992, 67 King Cr. Hurstville NSW 2456, CEO
A, 15, Michael Potter, 04-01-1995, 568 Bong Bong St. Horsley NSW 2530, SUPPORT
D, 16, Harry Potter, 04-01-1987, 568 Bong Bong St. Horsley NSW 2530, 20055, AVAILABLE
D, 17, James Bond, 02-14-1989, 7 Alan Bond St. Perth WA 6000, 20065, AVAILABLE
D, 18, Paris Hilton, 05-01-1977, 1 Hilton St. Melbourne VIC 3000, 10305, AVAILABLE
A, 19, Lady Gaga, 06-01-1992, 3 Pork st. Hobart TAS 7000, SUPPORT
D, 20, Robin Hood, 05-23-1999, 6 Nottingham Pl. Sydney NSW 2000, 10345, AVAILABLE
```

Comment: All other ways I tried just read all records at once which not met the requirement. Appreciate all helps

Comment: what is your problem/error?

Comment: @D.T Thanks for your response, it's not an error, just need an algorithm but I figured it out

Comment: It looks very suspicious that you are passing `scanner` as an argument, and then treating it like an ordinary local variable by reassigning it to `new Scanner`. You should either create a local variable there and not pass the argument, or create the `new Scanner` in the caller of your method.

Comment: Also it's `line.separator`, not `line.operator`.

Answer (score 0):

Create record like this

```
public record Employee(String id, String name, String date, String address) { }
```

Then try function like this:

```
public List<Employee> getEmployeesFromFile(File file) {
    Scanner scanner;
    List<Employee> employees;
    if (file.exists()) {
        try {
            scanner = new Scanner(file);
            employees = new ArrayList<>();
            while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
                String[] splitedNewLine = scanner.nextLine().split(",");
                employees.add(
                        new Employee(
                                splitedNewLine[0],
                                splitedNewLine[1],
                                splitedNewLine[2],
                                splitedNewLine[3]
                        )
                );
            }
            return employees;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return List.of();
        }

    } else {
        System.out.println("File not exists!!!");
        return List.of();
    }
}
```

This is only example how to read file and map lines to object employee. Try to adjust this code for you problem and data.

Answer (score 0):

You should use [Files.lines(Path path)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#lines-java.nio.file.Path-) method.

```
public static Stream<String> lines(Path path) throws IOException
```

It gives you your solution in one line